# extjs4 how to use Ext.data.DirectStore

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to invoke the function in server-side directly by using "Ext.data.DirectStore".
However, I'm having some problem currently.

Below is the code that I made by using mvc pattern.

```
Ext.define('DirectApp.store.DirectStore', {
extend : 'Ext.data.DirectStore',
constructor : function(cfg){
    cfg = Ext.apply(this, {
        storeId : 'directStore',
        model : 'DirectApp.model.DirectModel',  
        proxy : {
            type : 'direct',
            api : {
                create : DirectSvcImpl.updatePersonalRPC,
                update : DirectSvcImpl.updatePersonalRPC,
                read : DirectSvcImpl.getPersonalAllRPC,
                destory : DirectSvcImpl.destoryPersonalRPC
            }
        },
        autoLoad : true
    });                     
    this.callParent([cfg]);
}
```

});

Below are actions that I'm trying to do.

```
var tbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
items : [{
    text : 'Edit',
    handler : function(){
        var s = Ext.data.StoreMgr.get('directStore');

        var r = Ext.ModelManager.create({
            id : '346012',
            firstName : '',
            lastName : '',
            company : '',
            email : '',
            dob : '',
            age : 3,
            coworker : 'N/A'
        }, 'DirectApp.model.DirectModel');

        s.insert(0, r);
        s.sync();
    }       
},'-',{
    text : 'Remove',
    handler : function(){
        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('directStore');
            store.removeAt(0);
            store.sync();
    }
},'-']
```

});

First, when I remove record, I got below error.
"it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined""

For reference, I put the config, "directFn" and it works well.
Can't I use api config ?

Second, I want to send data into server side when I create newly record.
But, it shows like below. The data is null. How can I send data ?

```
action: "DirectSvcImpl"
data: null
method: "getPersonalAllRPC"
tid: 1
type: "rpc"
```

please give me an advice. I'm holding on this issue for week.

Comment: It would be good if you can make an example on jsfiddle.

Comment: would you tell me more details ? I'm having this problem for a long time. almost exhausted. !!